# Colocar un icono o imagen como indicador en una celda

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

No he logrado que el color con el que pinto determinada tr o td de mi tabla se guarde, siempre al cerrar la página y volverla abrir se quita, ya busque bastante, quizás con las palabras incorrectas, pero no encuentro solución, lo que quiero, ya sea con un boton, radio o check (este iría en un td de mi tabla) ponga un icono o imagen (en otro td) y que no se borre, tipo cuando seleccionas la banderita en hotmail para indicar importante el correo, pero que no se pueda volver a modificar

Comment: Porfavor agrega tu código

Comment: ¿al código de pintar la celda te refieres?, porque lo del icono no tengo nada aún, no se si se pueda, estaba pensando también en que el checkbox o el radio se queden seleccionados una vez los cliques, igual, que no se puedan modificar ‍♂️